# Kali Linux hangs on boot after hard reset

Tags: kali-linux, troubleshooting, system-recovery

I had to perform a hard reset after my machine became unresponsive. Now when I try to boot, it hangs as shown in this image: [image: boot hang].

I am able to boot into recovery mode, so have access to a terminal I can use to fix the problem, but I'm just not sure what that fix is.

```
$ uname -a
Linux Kali 4.8.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.5-1kali1 (2016-11-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is some info on graphics drivers: [image: graphics drivers]

Comment: I tried that with `apt remove xserver-xorg-video-intel` but still have the same problem. Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not nowhere near an expert but try configuring xorg

```
 -configure xorg
```

Or maybe

```
 apt-get purge xorg*;apt-get install xorg*
```

I would even try going into the grub terminal and checking out the dmesg | less output

Your command line is there for root@kali your gnome environment just ain't loading ... you might try installing kde and switching your kali environment from gdm to sddm.